# Get access to result sets from one stored procedure inside another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that has 5 Select statements and as I understand when I run it I get 5 result sets.

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services to generate some reports.

I would like to run that stored procedure from SSRS and use 3 of 5 result sets. I read that it is currently impossible because only one (top first) result set is taken by SSRS.

My idea was to create second stored procedure that would execute first one and union 3 out of 5 result sets and return only one newly created result set. But I have no idea how to iterate/or get access to result sets in stored procedure from executed stored procedure.

Also when I execute a stored procedure from another stored procedure, I can see that result sets from the first one are also printed in SQL Server Management Studio, so I believe that problem will be the same when moving to SSRS.

Do you have any hints on how can I access results sets from one stored procedure in another, manipulate them and make sure that only newly created result set will be returned so that I can use it in SSRS?

Thanks!

Comment: You won't be able to selectively consume result sets like that in T-SQL. (Externally from C#, etc., sure.) Have you considered refactoring the stored procedure that's outputting multiple result sets? i.e.: move each result set into a view or into a table valued user-defined function that can then be consumed individually.

Comment: ^ right, and then you could make a _different_ stored procedure just for SSRS that unions those views/functions without having to repeat the logic anywhere.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning " into a table valued user-defined function that can then be consumed individually" -> could you provide me with a simple example?

Comment: Prefer to use [Inline table-valued functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine#inline-table-valued-function-tvf) falling back to [Multi-statement table-valued functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine#multi-statement-table-valued-function-mstvf) if you can't rewrite the code as a single select statement.